# How do I let a screen know other screen's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Now I am trying to let a screen containing some lists know other screen's state.

The main screen contains some Form Components which user can input text to.
Other screens, Form Components contain some TextInput forms.

If a user inputs some texts into some form and then if this user puts a back button or a save-button, I want to change the main screen's state of these form components to be like "Editing", "Not Edit" or "Complete".

How to change the state of each form component's state on the Main screen?

[image: this picture is the main screen. Please focus on Red characters. There will be changed if a user will input some text into a form on other screens.]

This picture is the main screen. Please focus on Red characters. There will be changed if a user will input some text into a form on other screens.

This is a input-screen

```
  handleOnpress() {
const db = firebase.firestore();
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/form1`).add({
  form1 : [
    { fullname: this.state.fullname },
    { middleName: this.state.middleName },
    { reason: this.state.reason },
    { birthPlaceCity: this.state.birthPlaceCity },
    { birthPlaceCountry: this.state.birthPlaceCountry },
    { Citizinchip: this.state.Citizinchip },
    { aboutMaridge: this.state.aboutMaridge },
    { fromTermOfMaridge: this.state.fromTermOfMaridge },
    { ToTermOfMaridge: this.state.ToTermOfMaridge },
    { nameOfSpouse: this.state.nameOfSpouse },
    { birthdateOfSpouse: this.state.birthdateOfSpouse },
    { fromTermOfExMaridge: this.state.fromTermOfExMaridge },
    { ToTermOfExMaridge: this.state.ToTermOfExMaridge },
    { nameOfExSpouse: this.state.nameOfExSpouse },
    { birthdateOfExSpouse: this.state.birthdateOfExSpouse }]

 })
  .then(() => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <InfoHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}>申請者情報１ 
      </InfoHeader>
      <Notes />
      <QuestionTextSet onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ 
        fullname: text }); }} placeholder={'例：留学太郎'}>姓名（漢字表記） 
      </QuestionTextSet>
      <QuestionTextSet onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ 
        middleName: text }); }}>本名以外に旧姓・通称名(通名)・別名など他の名前が 
        あればローマ字で記入</QuestionTextSet>
      <QuestionTextSet onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ 
        reason: text }); }} placeholder={'例：結婚・離婚/ご両親の離婚のためな 
        ど'}>別名がある方はその理由</QuestionTextSet>
      <SubmitButton style={styles.saveButton} onPress= 
       {this.handleOnpress.bind(this)}>保存</SubmitButton>

       <Copyrights />

     </ScrollView>
   );
```

This is the main screen.

```
class WHApply extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <WHApplyBar navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      <WHApplyIndexBar />
      <HWApplyMailBar />
      <HWApplyList navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      <Agreement />
      <SubmitButton>同意して送信</SubmitButton>
      <Logout />
      <Copyrights />
    </ScrollView>
  );
 }
}
```

And this is a code of HWApplyList.
This component is import to the main screen.

```
  class HWApplyList extends React.Component {
    state = {
       fontLoaded: false,
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
     await Font.loadAsync({
     FontAwesome: fontAwesome,
   });

   this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
   return (

    <View style={styles.container}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { 
     this.props.navigation.navigate('PersonalInfo1'); }} >
      <View style={styles.listBox}>
        <Text style={styles.listBoxText}>
            申請者情報１
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.inputBotton}>
          <Text style={styles.inputBottonText}>未入力</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          {
            this.state.fontLoaded ? (
              <View style={styles.navigationButton}>
                <Text style={styles.navigationButtonIcon}>{'\uf0da'} 
        </Text>
              </View>
            ) : null
         }
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: The state needs to be in a common parent above your to components. This gets passed down to the other components. 

Please provide an example of what you **have tried**.

Comment: I also think you may want to look into flux (https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or redux (https://redux.js.org/), this in simple terms could allow you to have one common global state that's shared across all components.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and asking .
I pasted my code related with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, you will also need to pass a handler function to the screen child. This handle function will allow your child screen to modify the parent's state.

Something like

```
onChange(value) {
  this.setState({value});    
}
render() {
  return (
    <Screen1 value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
    <Screen2 value={this.state.value}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an advice.
But I have to save some data each user input on form into local device.
Because, if I don't do that, all of data will be gone,right?

So, now I am wondering to find way to keep some data on local device and be visible on each form screens.

Comment: The user input should be saved in the parent component state, this value will be then visible to all child screen as it is passed as a prop

Answer (score 0):

When you start to make many components that uses each other's state, Using a tool like "redux" makes it much easier.
Instead of putting your data ( that's you want it to be shared with the other components ) in a particular component state. you can create a common state for the whole app and you can access this state from any component.

here's a good article:
[Understanding Redux: The World’s Easiest Guide to Beginning Redux](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6)